# Factorization and Squares

Tags: number-theory, permutations, combinations

Let $M = 1!\times2!\times3!\times4!\times5!\times6!\times7!\times8!\times9!$. How many factors of $M$ are perfect squares?

I tried to solve it by expanding the factorials and seeing the perfect squares, but I think this method is long. I am just looking for a better solution.

Comment: Maybe you can write $M=1^9 \times 2^8 \times 3^7 \times 4^6 \times \dots \times 8^2 \times 9$

Comment: @MattiP. Then what should I do to list out the non - prime perfect square factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.  If $N = \prod p_i^{a_i}$ where $p_i$ are prime, is the prime factorization of $N$ then all factors of $N$ are in the form $\prod p_i^{k_i}$ where $0 \le k_i \le a_i$.  And the square factory of the form of $\prod p_i^{k_1}$ where $0 \le k_i \le a_i$ and $k_i$ is even.

Hint 2:  $M=1!\times ..... \times 9! =$

$1*2^8*3^7*4^6*5^5*6^4*7^3*8^2*9=$

$2^{8+12+4+6}3^{7+4+2}5^57^3 = 2^{30}*3^{13}*5^5*7^3$.

So the square factors are of the form $2^a3^b5^c7^d$ where $0 \le a \le 30; 0\le b \le 13; 0\le c\le 5; 0\le d\le 3$.  And $a,b,c,d$ are even.

Hint 3:  How many even $a$s are there between $0...30$?  How many even $b$s are there between $0... 13$?  How many combinations of the two are there.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just give you hints:

$1)$ What are the prime factors of $M$?

$2)$ Find the prime factorisation itself

$3)$ Count the numbers having even powers of those prime numbers such that the powers aren't higher than the powers in the factorisation of $M$

Comment: I factorised $M$ into its prime factors but I can't understand how to list out the different non-prime factors which are perfect squares.

Comment: I can tell you $2^3 \cdot 3^2$ has $4$ such factors without actually computing them - this is because squares have even powers of primes in their factorisation and you should look for even powers only